# passing checkboxlist selected items as a concatenated string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0, concatenation, checkbox

I am trying to pass the selected items from a checkboxlist in asp.net (vs 2005/.net 2.0) as a concatenated string.

Currently my .aspx is

```
        <asp:CheckBoxList id="checkbox1" AutoPostBack="False" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" TextAlign="Right" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Carrots</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Lettuce</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Olives</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Onions</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">Tomato</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Pickles</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And the .aspx.vb is (inside the Protected Sub for submit)

```
    For Each li As ListItem In checkbox1.Items
        If li.Selected = True Then
            checkbox1.Text = checkbox1.Text + "," + li.Text
        End If
    Next
```

Which is written to the db via

```
checkbox1.Text = dv(0)("Salad").ToString()
```

When I select and save, I am currently getting an error

### Server Error in '/' Application.

'checkbox1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

Parameter name: value

Any thoughts on how to concatenate the selected checkbox items

For example, if some selects Carrots, Lettuce, and Tomato;

```
checkbox1 = 1,2,5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are assigning to a variable like you describe you are returning.

```
string list = "";
For Each li As ListItem In chkQ4.Items
        If li.Selected = True Then
            list = list + "," + li.Text
        End If
    Next
```

is how you should write the line above.

In C# using linq, I would write

```
var list =  checkbox1.Items
.Cast<ListItem>()
.Where(item => item.Selected == true)
.Select(item => item.Value);
var result = string.Join(",",list);
```

which I believe is the following in VB

```
Dim list = checkbox1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Where(Function(item) item.Selected = True).[Select](Function(item) item.Value)
Dim result = String.Join(",", list.ToArray())
```

Comment: I think the last line should be: var result = string.Join(",",list.ToArray());  Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little example

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Carrots</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Apples</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Lettuce</asp:ListItem>        
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<br />
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Concatenate" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

Codebehind:

```
 Private Sub SaveItems(ByVal strItems As String)

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("user id=sa;password=abcd;database=BD_Test;server=SERVNAME")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into CheckItems values (@ItemId)", cn)
    Dim cmdPar As New SqlParameter("@ItemId", SqlDbType.Char, 1)

    If strItems.Split(",").Length > 0 Then

        cmd.Parameters.Add(cmdPar)
        Using cn
            cn.Open()
            Using cmd 
            ''Split the existing selected values, store it in an array 
            ''and iterate to get each element of it to save it in the DB
            For Each strItem As String In strItems.Split(",")                    
                    cmd.Parameters("@ItemId").Value = strItem
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()                    
            Next
            End Using  
            Me.Literal1.Text = "Items saved"
        End Using

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Literal1.Text = ""

    For Each l As ListItem In Me.CheckBoxList1.Items

        ''Concatenate keeping the order of the items in your CheckboxList
        If l.Selected Then
            Me.Literal1.Text = Me.Literal1.Text & l.Value & ","
        End If

    Next

    ''Remove the final "," in case its at the end of the string 
    ''to avoid db issues and selected items issues
    If Right(Me.Literal1.Text, 1) = "," Then
        Me.Literal1.Text = Left(Me.Literal1.Text, Me.Literal1.Text.Length - 1)
    End If

    ''You can also save the items directly after concatenating
    ''Me.SaveItems(Me.Literal1.Text)

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Me.SaveItems(Me.Literal1.Text)

End Sub
```

The expected result is to have the selected values of the items on the page literal:

```
1,3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your method, it is sending the first item selected instead of a string all items selected.  Any Thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the code assuming that you have a table called CheckItems with one field to save each item on it. You could also save all the built string "1,2,3" but you would need to remove the "for each" statement so the cmd.Parameters("@ItemId").Value take only the whole text in the literal and perform the saving once. Let me know if it worked.